# How do I extract the list of serial numbers from a Certificate Revocation List in C# without using third party libraries?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, certificate-revocation

I've connected to a MS PKI Certificate Revocation List distribution point and obtained the CRL

What's the most straightforward way to extract the list of serial numbers from the CRL without using third party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to unroll the CRL by using unmanaged CryptoAPI functions (through p/invoke, of course). Generally, you will have to the following high-level step-by-step:

1. [CertCreateCRLContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376036(v=vs.85).aspx) -- this function will return a pointer to a CRL_CONTEXT structure.
2. Use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` .NET method to convert `pCrlInfo` pointer of `CRL_CONTEXT` structure to `CRL_INFO` structure.
3. `rgCRLEntry` is an array of pointers (array size is determined by `cCRLEntry` member of `CRL_INFO`).
4. Iterate over this array by incrementing starting pointer by the size of `CRL_ENTRY` structure.
5. `SerialNumber` member of `CRL_ENTRY` is a byte array. You can directly use `Marshal.Copy(IntPtr, Byte[], Int32, Int32)` method to copy unmanaged array to managed. This will give you serial number. Repeat steps 4-5 for each CRL entry.

Do not forget to release pointer to `CRL_CONTEXT` structure by calling [CertFreeCRLContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376076(v=vs.85).aspx) function when finished to prevent memory leaks.